# Sorting both Alpanumeric and Numeric column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Here is my table data:

```
 - file_number -   status
 - ABC099    -     running
 - ABC100    -     running
 - ABC101    -     removed
 - ...
 - ABC1001   -     removed
 - ABC1002   -     removed
 - ABC1003   -     running
 - BCA099    -     running
 - BCA100   -      removed
 - BCA101   -      running
 - ...
 - BCA1001   -     removed
 - BCA1002   -     running
 - BCA1003   -     running
```

This query returns the correct answer with file_number sorted:

```
SELECT file_number,status FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(file_number) asc
```

But I want to sort the status column as well i.e all the running files should come first and removed files should be displayed at the end.

Expected result:

```
 - file_number  -  status
 - ABC099    -     running
 - ABC100    -     running
 - ABC1003   -     running
 - ...
 - BCA099    -     running
 - BCA101   -      running
 - ...
 - BCA1002   -     running
 - BCA1003   -     running
 - ABC101    -     removed
 - ABC1001   -     removed
 - ABC1002   -     removed
 - BCA100   -      removed 
 - BCA1001   -     removed
```

Comment: Your query sorts by length only

Comment: See `FIELD ()`.

Comment: SELECT file_number,status FROM table ORDER BY LENGTH(file_number) asc, status desc. This too does not work

Comment: @Strawberry :Could u please explain

Comment: Explain what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast `file_number` as `signed` in order to make your order by the numeric part. 
And then add `status desc` part into ORDER BY clause to provide the desired alphabetical order if you have only two options for status column :

```
SELECT file_number,status
  FROM `table` 
 ORDER BY status DESC, CAST(file_number AS signed)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ae229382205d32c2f8295fd184d7c0bb)</kbd>

**Update :** If you also have different letter combinations for prefixing the file numbers and want to order prominently by them, then consider adding this column into ORDER BY list as the first component :

```
SELECT file_number,status
  FROM `table` 
 ORDER BY status DESC, file_number, CAST(file_number AS signed)
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ca9fb616a30cbe26badb0f3b3af2b1cf)</kbd>

Comment: Tried but does not sort by file_number

Comment: @MEGHAPOOJARY have you looked at the demo? which yields the results exactly as you wish.

Comment: my table has file names as ABC001,ABC002 etc as well as BCA001,BCA002 etc and CAB001,CAB002 etc

Comment: please exactly state the sample data and desired results by editing your question @MEGHAPOOJARY

Comment: Edited the question.. In your demo two the file_number is sorted not the status.

Comment: well OK I fixed as dessired @MEGHAPOOJARY

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
SELECT file_number,status
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY status desc,
     LENGTH(file_number) asc,
     file_number asc
```

First you should order by status then you should order by length. Don't order by length first.

Comment: It does not sort by file_number but does sort by status